# Iptables - Limit Connections per Port

Tags: iptables, authentication, shadowsocks

I'm currently interested in setting up a server running a software called [shadowsocks](https://github.com/Long-live-shadowsocks/shadowsocks)- to quickly summarize my problem, shadowsocks authenticates users via a port number and password, and given the nature of the service (accounts are shared via qr codes and base64 encoded strings containing credentials), it would be in my best interest to limit how many connections I have per port at any given time (i.e. limiting each used shadowsocks port to 3 connections at a time, which equates to up to 3 users sharing the same set of credentials).

How could I go about doing this using iptables (or anything else that serves the same purpose)? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Look at the end of: `iptables -m connlimit -h`